# Routing Design Pattern In Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have found good tutorial on Routing design pattern at Swift

Can some one explain it or create it in Objective-C?

**GOAL**

To jump from one view controller to any other view and vice - versa

Means user can jump at any view to any view using this pattern

https://medium.com/commencis/routing-with-mvvm-on-ios-f22d021ad2b2

Comment: The article code has nothing Swift specific e.g Tuples or generics. The explanation remains the same. The code is more or less a direct language syntax conversion.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of flow I use *flow coordinators*. It just means that in the view controller itself you don't have a hardcoded destination view controller, you just call some delegate (I call him `flowDelegate`) and this delegate decides what to do next. The sample call would look like this

Obj-C:

```
@class HomeViewController;

@protocol HomeFlowDelegate

- (void)didTapRegistrationButtonInViewController:(HomeViewController*)viewController;

@end

@interface HomeViewController: UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,weak) id<HomeFlowDelegate> flowDelegate;

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (void)registrationButtonTapped {
    [self.flowDelegate didTapRegistrationButtonInViewController:self];
}

@end
```

Swift:

```
protocol HomeFlowDelegate {
    func didTapRegistrationButton(in viewController: HomeViewController)
}

class HomeViewController: ViewController {
    weak var flowDelegate: HomeFlowDelegate?

    func registrationButtonTapped() {
        flowDelegate?.didTapRegistrationButton(in: self)
    }
}
```

The flow delegate can than decide e.g. whether to push new screen or present it modally or do whatever flow would be appropriate.

This approach means that view controllers are independent and can be reused anywhere in the app. You just have to make sure that when a view controller comes on screen it has a `flowDelegate` assigned.

Comment: The question is clearly asking for an answer in Objective-C, not Swift.

Comment: Added my approach in Obj-C